# how to add xxx.db file into my project in android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

i have xxx.db (SQLite file) where i want to add him to my android app
in my android app under src i open new directory where i add "test.db"

then in my app what should i write in order to get the db ?

```
String myPath = "com.countryCityGame/databases/test.db";
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

i am sure mypath is spelled wrong ' what is the current position of the dp file once the app is inside the emulator .
should i insert the db into the manifest or somehing else ?
thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All databases that stored on phone not on SDCard are located in /data/data/com.PackageName/databases/test.db

See [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)  tutorial for using your own database in Android